# How I can install latest TZ Update to JRE 1.6

Tags: java, timezone, java-6, tzdata

I have legacy software that need Java6. I'm trying to update java TZ library via tzupdater.jar. I have successfully installed tzdata2019c.tar.gz , but couldn't install tzdata2020a

Here are details:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Borland\Java\Sun1.6.0_13\bin>java -jar tzupdater.jar -v -l file:///c:/util/tzdata2020a.tar.gz
Using file:///c:/util/tzdata2020a.tar.gz as source for tzdata bundle.
java.home: C:\Program Files (x86)\Borland\Java\Sun1.6.0_13
java.vendor: Sun Microsystems Inc.
java.version: 1.6.0_13
tzupdater version 2.3.0-b01
JRE tzdata version: tzdata2019c
Downloaded file to C:\Users\klin.rl\AppData\Local\Temp\tz.tmp_5\tzdata.tar.gz
tzupdater tool would update with tzdata version: tzdata2020a
**javazic: fatal error: unknown time mode: R**

C:\Program Files (x86)\Borland\Java\Sun1.6.0_13\bin>
```

I have found no answer in the internet.

Comment: I would suggest posting this to superuser instead of stackoverflow (https://superuser.com/)

Comment: Are you sure java 1.6 (which, mind you, is no longer supported since dicember 2018) is supported by this TZ update (which I'm assuming is the IANA tz data)?